# how to wrap text and add space between polylines using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have found this donut chart example. it is good one but I am having trouble understanding it and I am having problems with long text (wrappping) and labels overlapping one another when text is wrapped?

https://plnkr.co/edit/sAbnep00GMRkx5Xey6gL?p=preview&preview

This is the code: I removed the css as it was taking a lot of space.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  
</head>

<body>

  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function(d3) {
      'use strict';

      var width = 660;
      var height = 690;
      var radius = 150;
      var donutWidth = 75;
      var legendRectSize = 18;
      var legendSpacing = 4;

      var color = d3.scale.category20(); //builtin range of colors

      var s = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

      var legend_group = s.append('g').attr('transform',
        'translate(' + (width / 3) + ',' + (height / 1.4) + ')');
      var svg = s.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
          ',' + (radius) + ')');

      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
        .outerRadius(radius);

      var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
        .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

      var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) {
          console.log(d);
          return +d.count;
        })
        .sort(null);

      var tooltip = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'tooltip');

      tooltip.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'label');

      tooltip.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'count');

      tooltip.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'percent');

      d3.csv('weekdays.csv', function(error, dataset) {
        dataset.forEach(function(d) {
          d.count = +d.count;
          d.enabled = true; // NEW
        });

        var path = svg.selectAll('path')
          .data(pie(dataset))
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', arc)
          .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(d.data.label);
          }) // UPDATED (removed semicolon)
          .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
          }); // NEW

        path.on('mouseover', function(d) {
          var total = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) {
            return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // UPDATED
          }));
          var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10;
          tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label);
          tooltip.select('.count').html(d.data.count);
          tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%');
          tooltip.style('display', 'block');
        });

        path.on('mouseout', function() {
          tooltip.style('display', 'none');
        });
        var key = function(d) {
          return d.data.label;
        };

        makeTexts();
        makePolyLines();
        
        /* OPTIONAL
        path.on('mousemove', function(d) {
          tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 10) + 'px')
            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 10) + 'px');
        });
        */

        var legend = legend_group.selectAll('.legend')
          .data(color.domain())
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'legend')
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
            var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
            var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2;
            var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
            var vert = i * height - offset;
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
          });

        legend.append('rect')
          .attr('width', legendRectSize)
          .attr('height', legendRectSize)
          .style('fill', color)
          .style('stroke', color) // UPDATED (removed semicolon)
          .on('click', function(label) { // NEW
            var rect = d3.select(this); // NEW
            var enabled = true; // NEW
            var totalEnabled = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // NEW
              return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0; // NEW
            })); // NEW

            if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') { // NEW
              rect.attr('class', ''); // NEW
            } else { // NEW
              if (totalEnabled < 2) return; // NEW
              rect.attr('class', 'disabled'); // NEW
              enabled = false; // NEW
            } // NEW

            pie.value(function(d) { // NEW
              if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled; // NEW
              return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // NEW
            }); // NEW

            path = path.data(pie(dataset)); // NEW

            path.transition() // NEW
              .duration(750) // NEW
              .attrTween('d', function(d) { // NEW
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); // NEW
                this._current = interpolate(0); // NEW
                return function(t) { // NEW
                  return arc(interpolate(t)); // NEW
                }; // NEW
              }); // NEW
            makeTexts();
            makePolyLines();

          }); // NEW

        legend.append('text')
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
          .text(function(d) {
            return d;
          });

        function midAngle(d) {
          return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
        }

        function makeTexts() {
          var text = svg.selectAll(".labels")
            .data(pie(dataset), key);

          text.enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .classed("labels", true)
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.data.label + " (" + d.data.count + ")";
            });

          svg.selectAll(".labels").style("display", function(d) {
            if (d.value == 0) {
              return "none";
            } else {
              return "block";
            }
          });

          text.transition().duration(1000)
            .attrTween("transform", function(d) {

              this._current = this._current || d;
              var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
              this._current = interpolate(0);
              return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate(" + pos + ")";
              };
            })
            .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
              this._current = this._current || d;
              var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
              this._current = interpolate(0);
              return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
              };
            });

          text.exit()
            .remove();
        }

        function makePolyLines() {
          var polyline = svg.selectAll("polyline")
            .data(pie(dataset), key);

          polyline.enter()
            .append("polyline");

          svg.selectAll("polyline").style("display", function(d) {
            console.log(d, "hello")
            if (d.value == 0) {
              return "none";
            } else {
              return "block";
            }
          });

          polyline.transition().duration(1000)
            .attrTween("points", function(d) {
              this._current = this._current || d;
              var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
              this._current = interpolate(0);
              return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
              };
            });

          polyline.exit()
            .remove();
        }
        



        

      });

    })(window.d3);
  </script>
</body>

</html>



label,count
Testing with some long textAnd it conitues,3 
Active_Integrated,286
Assigned,19
Active_not_Integrated,56
Assigned_Waiting,13
Complete,184
Dev_Waiting,17
Global_Screening,23
In Progress,14
In_Development,12
New,76
Pending_CTL_Approval,38
Test,1
Rejected,50
RETIRED with long text and contiues,37
```

This is the wrap function:

```
const wrap=(_text: {  each: (arg0: (i: any, d: any, p: any) => void) => void; }, width: number)=> {
    _text.each((d: any,i: any,nodes: any[])=> {
      var text = d3.select(nodes[i]),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line: string[] = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy") || "0"),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
      while (word = words.pop()) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        if (tspan?.node()!.getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          line = [word];
          tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineHeight + "em").text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

If you uncheck some of the labels (see print screen below), it will move the labels and they start overlapping.

[image]

Any help, please?

Comment: Have you considered simply reducing the size of the text and/or replacing the text with shorter strings? You've still got the tooltips and legend to provide more detailed information and, honestly, the design is a bit cluttered as is.

Comment: If I reduce the text size it will become unreadable.